# Validate OAuth API key and API secret?

Tags: api, validation, oauth, api-key

I am creating small blog like project, in which i am using OAuth login system. For all providers API key and Secret will be enter from setting page. I want to validate key and secret, is it valid or not on setting page?

please help me.

I implemented Yahoo, Google, Facebook, Twitter , MSN and Linkedin

Comment: Are you creating an OAuth service provider? If yes, in what language?

Comment: Please do include lots more details and an example use case too. Are you using Google, Facebook as *identity providers* for visitors (thats the job of OpenID) or do you want your app to perform *specific services* for visitors? And the language you are using (I did it in PHP)